# Does anyone know of any good open source Geodjango apps to dig through?

Tags: gis, geodjango

I'm looking to build a small GIS in my spare time and have been digging into Geodjango.

I've been trying to find examples of open source Geodjango projects to look through, but I have had little luck, so here I am.  I've been through most of the tutorials I could find, but they all seem to stop at the same point and I'm curious to look into some more complicated real-world code.

Anyone know if/where I can find some?  Anything will suffice, but stuff using the Google Earth API as opposed to Open Layers would be ideal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

everyblock.com recently released their source code for their GeoDjango-based site. I've been digging through it - it's an interesting case study. It includes the public-facing site, a JSON API and some back-end data aggregation and map-generating code. Links and more info can be found at: http://www.everyblock.com/code/

Comment: Can anyone share anything in the current scenario = New applications built using Django + geoDjango integrated within Django. I have to use it in a project and I feel like I am not getting the hang of things. Maybe digging through actual code will help?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend reading about what a [GIS mapping stack](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/takecontrolofyourmaps) is all about first. Once you understand where GeoDjango fits within this stack, there is a [geodjango-basic-apps](http://code.google.com/p/geodjango-basic-apps/) Google repository that gives some GeoDjango examples. The examples that you find online will swap certain portions of the stack (e.g. Open Layers for Google Maps API or MapServer for GeoServer) but the the design patterns and ideas are very similar if not the same in numerous cases.

Comment: Thanks, great article! I did not know about it.  I've actually done much of the stuff at the Google repos as well as the Geodjango tutorial.  I also work at a GIS software company so I have a little prior knowledge, even though much of my work is not GIS related.  The reason I wanted to use the Google Earth api was because my understanding is that the Google Earth API is a compiled plug-in so it should typically be faster than something like the Javascript based OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0):

MarineMap is a web-based tool for open and participatory spatial planning in the marine environment. For more information about MarineMap, visit http://marinemap.org

Code: https://code.google.com/p/marinemap/

Demo: http://southcoast.marinemap.org/marinemap/

Comment: Seems that marinemap.org has moved over to http://www.seasketch.org/; found it via the WayBackMachine (it used to to a 302 redirect, but I guess they shut down the original server)